# Sending state to parent component freeze current component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginning a project in react.
I want to handle 2 component ( "chambre" (a room) and "patient" (user)) in my main app.js. I'm currently doing "chambre", and everything works for now.

[image]

I want to send the state of chambre to app.js ( which will also receive patient.state, in order to put a patient in a room )

It works, but when i uncomment the

```
this.props.update("chambre",json); inside chambre.componentdidmount()
```

the input and state.id_chambre in the render refuses to change, 
               `<td className="resume">{this.aff_liste_chambre()}</td>`
doesn't show anything anymore
[image].

The state doesn't get updated and i get this 
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method. in Chambre (at App.js:98) in component (created by Route) –

I would like help to understand why. Thank you

Here's my code

```
class Chambre extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        liste_chambre : [] ,
        id_chambre : 0,
        idpatient : 0,
        deplacement : -1
    }
    this.show_id = this.show_id.bind(this);
    this.gerer_chambre = this.gerer_chambre.bind(this);
    this.aff_liste_chambre =this.aff_liste_chambre.bind(this); 
    this.changer_filtre = this.changer_filtre.bind(this);
    this.ajouter_patient = this.ajouter_patient.bind(this);
    this.plein = this.plein.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
        fetch( "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rooms" , { method: "GET" })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((json) => {
            this.setState({liste_chambre : json});
          //  this.props.update("chambre",json);
        })  
    }, 1000 );   
} 
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
render() {
    return (<div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    Gerer la chambre numéro : 
                    <input type= "number" name= "id_chambre" onChange= {this.handleChange}
                    value= {this.state.id_chambre} />
                </thead>
                <td>{this.gerer_chambre()}</td>
                <td className="resume">{this.aff_liste_chambre()}</td>
            </table>
        </div>);
}

class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        patient : [],
        chambre : [],
        filtre : [],
        personnel : []
    }
    this.deplacer_patient = this.deplacer_patient.bind(this);
    this.changer_filtre = this.changer_filtre.bind(this);
    this.achat_filtre = this.achat_filtre.bind(this);
    this.chekcNotPatient = this.chekcNotPatient.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
}

componentWillUnmount() {
}


handleChange(name,value) {
    this.setState({ [name] : value });
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>

            < BrowserRouter >
                < div >
                    <header className="App-header">
                        <a className="App-link"
                            href="https://reactjs.org"
                            target="_blank"
                            rel="noopener noreferrer">
                            <Clock />
                        </a>
                        < ul >
                            < li >< Link to= "/resume" > Resume </ Link ></ li >
                            < li >< Link to= "/patient" > Patient </ Link ></ li >
                            < li >< Link to= "/chambre" > Chambre </ Link ></ li >
                            </ ul >
                    </header>
                    < Route path= "/resume" component= {() => < Resume />} />
                    < Route path= "/patient" component= {() => < Patient />} />
                    < Route path= "/chambre" component= {() => < Chambre onDeplace={this.deplacer_patient} onFiltre={this.changer_filtre} PatientDoNotExist={this.checkNotPatient} update={this.handleChange}/>} /> 

                    </ div >
                </ BrowserRouter >
        </div>)
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the console of your browser for JavaScript errors? If there are, can you post them?

Comment: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Chambre (at App.js:98)
    in component (created by Route)

Comment: Got this warning, but my component are mounted so i don't understand it

Comment: I checked the state and liste_chambre isn't updated anymore

Answer (score 0):

After setting your json in the state with `this.setState({liste_chambre : json});` you can use it anywhere in your component so if you want to send it to the parent you can use componentDidUpdate  `

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevState.liste_chambre!==this.state.liste_chambre){
         this.props.update("chambre",this.state.liste_chambre);
    }
}
```

and dont forget to clean up you interval with

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.timerID)
}
```

this might remove the warning